# Change date format in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a date column in my database. This column is writing the date like: `2016-05-31`. How can I change this, so it will secord the values like: `31/05/16` (dd/mm/yy).

Comment: Why you want to do this? `dd/mm/yy` is a horrible format (it can be read in 3 different ways, leading to 3 different dates and it is not Big-endian). `YYYY-MM-DD` is Big-endian, can only be read in one way and is easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing the MySQL standard way of storing/displaying dates. Of course, it's reliant on the client if you wish to change this formatting.

Within phpMyAdmin, this is a great use for the [transformation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html) feature, so much so that there is already a date formatter distributed with phpMyAdmin.

From the Structure page, I've clicked to "Edit" a row with type date, and have used `0,'%d.%m.%Y'` as my transformation options to get a result like `02.06.2016`:

[image: Edit dialog with transformation option]

Clicking the "Browser display transformation" link shows all the available transformation options. The date formatting uses the standard PHP date formatting strings, so to get your desired output you could use `0,'%d/%m/%y'`.